# Is there an industry standard on how many decimal places to display on an HMI screen?

Tags: standards

I can't seem to find anything, I'm trying to come up with a justification for how many decimal places to display on this Ignition SCADA system I'm building for a client. The answer might simply be that there is no industry standard, I'm just not sure.

Comment: I think it will depend on your interface and the degree of granularity your system needs, so I believe your guessing about the lack of a standard might be true

Answer (score 2):

This depends, keep enough decimal places that the user can discern the difference between a bunch of items easily.

But if you need a standard to go by, [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4483789/#:%7E:text=A%20suitable%20rule%20specifies%20up,blur%20the%20differences%20between%20them.) paper suggests that you use 2 decimal places

Personally, I've noticed that 2 is very common. I know it's a rule in currencies and of course finance/accounting fields that work with currencies. But the article above really helps solidify this idea. I've only schemed through what I needed for this answer, but I'm sure the author goes into more detail. Hopefully enough to convince you to stick to 2 for now.